# How do I make a mediaPlayer stop when another mediaPlayer starts so that they dont play on top of each other?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have 2 buttons that both play an mp3. When the first song is playing I want a click of the second song to stop the first song, and start the song that was clicked. also if the first button is pressed twice the second press resets the song.

basically I don't want the songs to play on top of each other when multiple buttons are pressed.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.placeyouknow:
    String url = "http://www.katastro.com/audio/facts/01%20That%20Place%20You%20Know.mp3";
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    mp.setDataSource(url);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    case R.id.fallen:
    String url1 = "http://www.katastro.com/audio/fallen/01%20Fallen.mp3";
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    mp.setDataSource(url1);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to implement a state machine to manage your player (start-stop-restart) instead of creating a new player every time a button is pressed

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm 13 and teaching this all to myself. Can you give me a description of how that might work?

Comment: Keep track of the last button pressed and if you get another button pressed either stop playback and start playing a new song or re-set the song being played

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample sound helper class I use for simple apps. I use it to play at most one resource at a time within my app, but you could modify it to play audio from some url instead.

```
public class Sound
{
private static MediaPlayer mp = null;

/** Stop old sound and start new one */
public static void play(Context context, int resource)
{
    stop(context);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.start();
}

/** Stop the music */
public static void stop(Context context)
{
    if (mp != null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoooaaaaa, losing handles on `MediaPlayer`s left and right.

First of all, for this particular activity, you should only put

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

in the `onCreate()` method of your activity. Delete the two you call in the `onClick()` method and move it to the `onCreate()` method.

From there, all you have to do is include a call to `mp.reset()` right before you call `mp.setDataSource()` and it should work just like you want it to!

Cheers